# Boundary conditions for enthalpy waves inside a pipe

Tags: waves, boundary-conditions, thermodynamics

So I'm trying to solve a form of the wave equation for sound produced by a vortex distribution $\vec{\omega}$ convecting at velocity $\vec{v}$ .

$$\left(\frac{1}{c_0^2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2\right)B=\nabla \cdot (\vec{\omega} \wedge \vec{v}) $$

The equation is found in [Theory of Vortex Sound](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052181281X) by M.S. Howe on page 120. The book formulates the equation in terms of [enthalpy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy) as opposed to pressure, I suppose because it takes on a simpler form. I'm trying to solve this equation on a pipe. Does anyone know of a reference that formulates the boundary conditions for the problem in terms of enthalpy, or should I just convert it to pressure?

Comment: Enthalpy is linear in $p$, so I would suspect Neumann and Dirichlet boundary conditions to be easily swapped between the two. Are you using some other BC (e.g., Cauchy)?

Comment: @kyle-kanos No I'm just using Neumann and Dirichlet bcs. I think what's confusing about this is I've never really seen enthalpy treated as a field quantity before the way pressure is. I've only seen it treated as a state quantity. So I'm not really sure how to go about doing the conversion. I assume B  = p + U*V doesn't hold when you're thinking of enthalpy as a field varying in space.

Comment: I typically use enthalpy for computing the energy component of the [Riemann problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_problem) in Eulerian hydrodynamics, but I have seen some hydrodynamic codes use enthalpy as a field variable--though I do not believe it is a conservative equation when using enthalpy.